# How can I draw individually on surfaceView?

Tags: android, view, android-canvas, surfaceview, android-graphics

I want to build a dx ball game. In my game, I want to draw a ball, a bar, bricks individually. It means when ball position is ready, the ball will draw; when bricks are ready bricks will draw. In the normal way, I lock surface holder then draw everything. Example:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while(ballPlay){
        try{
            gameCanvas = null;

            gameCanvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            gameCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
            ballPosition.drawBall(gameCanvas);
            for (int i = 0; i < brickCount; i++) {
                brick[i].drawBrick(gameCanvas);
            }
            gameBar.drawBar(gameCanvas);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if(gameCanvas!=null){
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(gameCanvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, we unlock it and post. But, how can I draw everything separately?

Comment: You may benefit from watching this old Google IO video on Real-Time games: https://youtu.be/U4Bk5rmIpic

Comment: If you are updating all the balls then you have to update all the balls but if you are updating only one ball then you can do it by invalidate(Dirty).This will update only that rect . for more info you can google it.